# deserialize name=value from file?

Tags: c#

I have a file in the form of Java properties file:

```
param1=value1
param2=value2
......
paramN=valueN
```

What is the easisest way to deserialize such a file in C# to something readable? (`List<string>` is fine)

I can change actual file representation to whatever, but it still should contain set of name=value strings.

Comment: It doesn't seem "javascript properties file". If it really is.. {param=value1, param=value2} you can use "new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(myFileStringedContent);"

Comment: i was talking about Java properties files, not Javascript http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var dict = lines.Select(s => s.Split(new char[] { '=' }))
                .ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]);
```

It reads all the lines into an array, splits all the lines into an array with key at index 0 and value at index 1, and finally creates a dictionary (key/value map).

You can access the values by:

```
dict["param1"] //this will return value1
```

Comment: thanks, i've modified code to trim spaces: s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim()